# Setting data row primary ID in TR ID for JQUERY Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using ASP.Net MVC and trying to set the datasource rowID value in each TR #ID attribute.
Problem is I'm getting table id=myDataTable - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0.
the controller returns:

```
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(List);
return Json(new
{
    sEcho = param.sEcho,
    iTotalRecords = result.Count,
    iTotalDisplayRecords = 10,
    aaData = json
},
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and **List** is a list of:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string DT_RowId {get;set;}
    public string NumeLocatie {get;set;}
}
```

DataTables initializer is:

```
    oSesizariTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        "scrollY": "600px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "ControlSLA/AjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "width": "30",
                "class": "details-control",
                "orderable": false,
                "mdata": null,
                "defaultContent": "",
                "targets": 0
            },
            { "targets": 1, "width": "30", "mdata": "NumeLocatie" },],
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "DeLa", "value": $('#sesizariDeLa').val() });
            aoData.push({ "name": "La", "value": $('#sesizariLa').val() });
            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                fnCallback(json)
            });
        }
    });
    $("#Refresh").click(function (e) {
        oSesizariTable.fnDraw();
    });
```

I've just started with ASP.Net and MVC... I can't get to the bottom of this!!!
Data sent from controller is:

```
{ draw = 1, recordsTotal = 2, recordsFiltered = 10, data = "[[\"DT_RowId\":\"ses_35335\",\"NumeLocatie\":\"Galati 1_\"],[\"DT_RowId\":\"ses_35342\",\"NumeLocatie\":\"3 Craiovei\"]]" }
```

and now the error is:

> table id=myDataTable - Requested unknown parameter 'NumeLocatie' for
>   row 0

After I click OK at the error prompt, the table shows every letter in the data in 1 row.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is only with rowID? it looks to me that you are not passing the right objects to the table. Is the table being populated correctly?

Comment: you're right. the data seems to be formatted incorrectly, because when I create a list of arrays of strings from my list of objects and return that, it's working, but I've verified the serialized list and it seems to be good JSON format. Updated the question to show data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found the problem, and decided to post an answer here, maybe someone else is going to have the same problem. Indeed, as @MarioLopez said (thanks for pointing me in the right direction), there was a problem with the data format:
This

```
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(List);
```

was enclosing the list of objects in double quotes:

```
data = "[[\"DT_RowId\"...
```

when it should've been:

```
data = [[\"DT_RowId\"...
```

So I just had to pass the list directly to the JSON response:

```
return Json(new
{
    sEcho = param.sEcho,
    iTotalRecords = result.Count,
    iTotalDisplayRecords = 10,
    aaData = list // this is the list<MyObj> not the jsonSerialiser
},
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Great answer! I think you should mark it as accepted, it will help other people in the future.